# React Native - Tela congela na navegação após atualizar SDK Expo

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo

Após atualizar SDK do 41 para o 43 a navegação utilizando @reatc-native-navigate/navigate
congela a tela ao retornar para a tela anterior.

```
dispatch(
        actions.profile.setValue({
            profile: {
                contactCompany: item
            }
        })
    );
    navigation.goBack()
```

Testei com navigation.navigate("home", {screen: "profile"})

mas o erro é o mesmo, quando entro na tela, ela funciona. Redirecionando para outra tela, para adicionar e selecionar contato, e retornando, a ela simplesmente congela.

Versão das denpendencias instaladas:

```
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.5",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.2",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "5.11.5",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
"react-native": "0.64.3",
"react": "17.0.1",
```

Fiz as alterações que o Expo propoem:

https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-43-aa9b3c7d5541

https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-42-579aee2348b6

O erro ocorre apenas em um módulo que já funcionava antes da atualização.
Não mostra nenhum erro no console e tambem a tela não quebra apenas congela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser algum conflito no *navigator* ao empilhar telas. Experimente usar a ***prop*** ***detachInactiveScreens*** como ***false***:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#detachinactivescreens

```
<Stack.Navigator detachInactiveScreens={false}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainTabsNavigator} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Essa *issue* pode estar relacionada:

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10096

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).